# Cron and interactive application

Tags: cron, root, graphical-user-interface

I want to schedule a gui application in cron, but there is a problem. When cron tries to run the scheduled task (amarok in my case) it throws `cannot connect to X server` error. I assume it is because the application is executed from my root account. 
Is it possible to run an application from a root but to pretend to be someone else?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cronjobs run in a very restricted environment, meaning it doesn't know where to find the X server (the `$DISPLAY` environment variable doesn't exist).

If you want to execute a X application from crontab, you need to first set the `$DISPLAY` environment variable.

Either call AmaroK like **pQd** said, or set it for the whole the cron-script:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0
# ...
* * * * * amarok
```

Also, I would recommend you to run this as the account you "want to be", rather than root, this is done by running `crontab -e` as the user.

**EDIT:**

You should also be able to do it like this:

```
* * * * * export DISPLAY=:0.0 && amarok
```

Comment: Thanks, yeah I am using `DISPLAY=:0.0 amarok.sh` - works perfect.

Answer (score 1):

i think it's bad idea, nevertheless you can execute as root:

```
su -c 'export DISPLAY=":0.0"; amarok' username
```

i assume x session is running and you do have user *username*.

but... you can run from cron scripts as non-root - so why do you insist on invoking it as root? there are also plenty of [command-line](http://moc.daper.net/) [controlled](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/) [media](http://mp3blaster.sourceforge.net/) players - maybe you do not need amarok after all?

to run script as non-root put in /etc/crontab

```
25 6    * * *   username /script/you/want/to/execute.sh
```

depending on location of commands you'll use you might need to add full path to them.

Comment: okay, how would I run cron scripts as non-root? So I won't see cannot connect to X server message?